# Jetty: inputstream in Handler always empty. how to get an input stream from client

Tags: jetty

I want to develop an ntrip caster based on jetty 9.4.27.
A http-client sends the data via http-POST.

the procedure (ntrip protocol) hast to be as follows:

1. client: send "POST /Mount-Point HTTP/1.1"
2. server: send status code 200 as confirmation (HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
3. client: wait until status code 200 is received
4. client: start sending data continuously

Important: the whole thing must run in one request

Steps 1 and 2 are working:
The invocation of the Jetty-handler works correctly.
the client receives the status code 200 and starts the data transfer. 
although the client writes to the output stream, the data does not arrive on the server.

baseRequest.getReader() and request.getReader() are always "empty".

What's wrong with my code?
A server implementation with simple sockets works fine with this client-programm.
Is something similar possible with Jetty ?

The client is implemented with a simple socket.
the simplified code looks like this ...

```java
// create Socket to connect jetty server
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
socket = new Socket(addr, port);
...
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
bufferedWriter.write(createHttpPost())  // Send POST /Mount-Point HTTP/1.1 ...
...
if (checkResponseCode200(response.toString())){
   // Status Code 200 received. send data continuously
   while(true){
      socket.getOutputStream().write(Utils.convertByteToByteArray(msg));
      socket.getOutputStream().flush();
   }
}
```

```java
/*
*  Jetty Programmcode
*/
package ch.dca.caster;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class JettyServer {
    private Server server;

    public void start() throws Exception {
        server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(128, 8));
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(1083);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});
        server.setHandler(new InitialHandler());
        server.start();
    }

   public class InitialHandler extends AbstractHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(String target,
                           Request baseRequest,
                           HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException

        {
           // printout Request-Header

           System.out.println("**** Before request.getReader() :  baseRequest = " + baseRequest);
           System.out.println("**** Header");
           Enumeration<String> headerValues = baseRequest.getHeaderNames();
           List<String> headerValuesList= Collections.list(headerValues);

           for(String s:headerValuesList){
                System.out.println(s + ": " + baseRequest.getHeader(s));
           }
           /* Result ....
               **** Before request.getReader() :  baseRequest = Request(POST //192.168.1.112/CHE8304A)@7698d57b
               **** Header
               Host: 192.168.1.112
               Authorization: Basic ZGNhcnRjbTpZaUpiYks4Ug==
               Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/2.0
               Content-Type: gnss/data
               User-Agent: NTRIP dca.telemetry.server
               Connection: close
           */

            //
            // Step 1: 
            // compliant to ntrip protocol:  first of all send status code 200 to the client
            //
            response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("OK");
            out.flush();

            //
            // Step 2: 
            // Client starts streaming the data as soon as code 200 is received
            // client: --> socket.getOutputStream().write(Utils.convertByteToByteArray(msg));
            //

            BufferedReader is = request.getReader(); // <----- not working: allways Empty !!!
            boolean doRead = true;
            while (doRead){
                int c = is.read();
                while (c > -1) {
                    System.out.print(int2Byte(c));
                    c = is.read();
                }

            }
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `System.out.println("baseRequest = " + baseRequest);` before you call `request.getReader()` and run it again.  Then please edit/update this question with the details. (that should produce multiple lines of output, include them all please)

Comment: hello, i did the following ..
`System.out.println("**** Before request.getReader() :  baseRequest = " + baseRequest);
            BufferedReader is = request.getReader(); // <----- not working: allways Empty !!! `

Results in just one row:
`**** Before request.getReader() :  baseRequest = Request(POST //192.168.1.112/CHE8304A)@7698d57b`

Comment: That should dump the request details (request line and headers), do you really have no headers being sent on that request?

Comment: with use of `baseRequest.getHeader() ` the header entries look like this:    
  `POST //192.168.1.112/CHE8304A`
  [\n]`Authorization: Basic ZGNhcnRjbTpZaUpiYks4Ug==`
  [\n]`User-Agent: NTRIP pac.telemetry.server`
  [\n]`Connection: close`
  [\n]`Host: 192.168.1.112`
  [\n]`Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/2.0`
  [\n]`Content-Type: gnss/data`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the details, the comments section is a poor place to cover technical details.

Comment: good idea. thanks. modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

The request headers you indicated:

```
Host: 192.168.1.112
Authorization: Basic ZGNhcnRjbTpZaUpiYks4Ug==
Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/2.0
Content-Type: gnss/data
User-Agent: NTRIP dca.telemetry.server
Connection: close
```

There is no body content that's obvious with that set of headers.

There is generally 3 ways to send body content on an HTTP request ...

1. With a `Content-Length` header indicating the length of the body. (supported on HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, and even HTTP/2)
2. With a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header indicating a undetermined length of body content (only supported on HTTP/1.1, and requires a specific encoding format to function. [RFC7230: Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1))
3. Raw body content until the connection is closed. (old school HTTP/1.0 technique)

I would recommend using technique #1 or #2 for maximum compatibility with the specs and reduced complication with HTTP intermediaries (proxies, load balancers, caching servers, etc)

Another thing to pay attention to is the HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, etc..).
Not all methods support body content. (so stick with the POST you have indicated to eliminate that complication)